# How can I create amazon ses emails via api or any method?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, email-processing

I am using amazon ses service now i want every user that will register my website  to have ses mail .My website running on php

How can i do that any descriptive documentation will be really appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "every user ... to have ses mail"? Are you wanting to _send_ them emails, or are you wanting to create mailboxes for every user so that they can send & receive emails? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: yes create a mailboxe

Comment: Amazon SES can be used to send emails and it also allows processing of incoming emails (which are sent to an AWS Lambda function). However, it does not provide "mailboxes" where individual users can send and receive email. The closest AWS service that provides this capability is Amazon WorkMail, but it is typically used as a corporate emailing and calendar system (charged at $4 per user per month).